# Can you use a regex to split by elements you don't want?

Tags: .net, regex, powershell, split

I really hope I can articulate this well and I haven't had any luck googling for this.  Basically I have a string of email addresses which I'll express like this:

```
$string = "test@me.com,test2@me2.com;test3@me3.com:test4@me4.com;;::test5@me.com"
```

I know that I can do a split like this:

```
[system.collections.arraylist]$array  = $string.Split(":;,,")
$array.Remove("")
```

The above works great, but here i have to explictly define what the separator is.  I have a regex I use to then validate the structure of an email which got me to thinking.

Is it possible to define the split by what *isn't* in the string?  How could I express to split by whatever doesn't match my regex for validating the email?

Comment: What would be an example of something that isn't in your example string, but you would like to split on?

Comment: In this case it doesn't really matter.  As the regex itself doesn't matter, but instructing in the code to separate by whatever doesn't match the pattern I define.  I'm trying to keep the question on target and not run down a tangent.

Comment: Whats the difference between `it works matching all targets` and `it works splitting non-targets`?

Comment: That is not possible in a simple and efficient way. The hard way is provided by briantist. Use *known* delimiters in *split*, or the pattern to find what you do not know with *match*. Doing anything else will result in effeciency, readability, and maintainability loss.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without regex.

The [`Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method has [an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes an array of `[char]` and a `StringSplitOptions` value - you can use this to split the string at any occurrence of `,`, `;` or `:`, and then remove all empty entries:

```
$string =  "test@me.com,test2@me2.com;test3@me3.com:test4@me4.com;;::test5@me.com"
$separators = ",:;".ToCharArray()
$string.Split($separators,[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Which will return an array of strings containing the exact 5 email adresses you're interested in

Comment: This is a neat example, but still requires manually defining separators.  I'm wanting to see if it's possible to think of it in the reverse.  To separate by whatever doesn't match a pattern.  All the same, +1

Comment: Ahh, I totally missed that point, sorry. I like your idea (although it's harder than you think, especially if you start considering email addresses containing modifiers, internationalized domain names etc.)

Comment: I agree, which is why I didn't want to get caught up in the actual expression I'm using to match.  I was hoping the answer would be "hey put this <regex> around your regex and you're good!".  I viewed the concept as beneficial and applying elsewhere and thought I'd ask it.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question! I came up with this function:

```
function Split-MeNot {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipeline=$true
    )]
    [String]
    $String ,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Regex]
    $Pattern
)

    Process {
        $anti = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder($String)
        $Pattern.Matches($String) | Sort-Object Index -Descending | ForEach-Object {
            $null = $anti.Remove($_.Index, $_.Length)
        }
        $String.Split($anti.ToString(), [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
    }
}
```

### Breakdown

1. Create a new `[StringBuilder]` object based on the original string.
2. Find all of the matches associated with the regex pattern you have.
3. Sort them so that the we work on them in reverse order of where they appear in the string (since we're removing by index).
4. For each of those matches, remove it by index and length.
5. Split the string based on what's left (and remove the empties).

I tested with the following:

```
$str = "test@me.com,test2@me2.com;test3@me3.com:test4@me4.com;;::test5@me.com"
$pat = '[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+'

$str | Split-MeNot -Pattern $pat
```

I haven't done any more extensive testing than that, but it seemed to work well.

Comment: Alternative name: `Split-ReNot`

Comment: I like the approach, but that's a terrible Noun :-P

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Guilty. Couldn't help running `Invoke-Pun`

Answer (score 0):

Just use powershell's `-split` it can split on multiple instances of a character. If you make your regex look for multiples of any non-valid email character then you can do the split with one command like so:

```
$string -split '[^a-zA-Z0-9._%+@-]+'
```